# Sum value_count() output

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

[image: image showing output from below code]

```
homes_by_state = df_south.groupby(["state"])["property_type"].value_counts()
```

I want to output only "state" and total number of "property_type"

Comment: Please read how to write a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: `df_south['state'].value_counts()` ?

Comment: `df_south['state'].value_counts()` outputs all columns. I want to summarize `my_dataframe.shape` to `(3,)` using column `state` as my index and `property_type total` as my values. @ScottBoston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code `homes_by_state = df_south.groupby(["state"])["property_type"].count()` and it seems to have done the trick. `value_counts()` was outputting total for unique values in the column `property_type`. See snapshot [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBrGl.png)